# Some Strange Output Results in gfortran

Tags: formatting, fortran, output

I must have fell asleep during output formatting day in Fortran class, because these results are perplexing me.  Using gfortran 4.6,

this program

```
program f1
  real :: x=65246514
  write(*,*) x
end program f1
```

results in

```
   65246512.0
```

This program

```
program f1
  real :: x=65245.6525
  write(*,*) x
end program f1
```

results in

```
   65245.6523
```

Finally, this program

```
program f1
  real :: x=65226545.6525
  write(*,'(F14.4)') x
end program f1
```

results in

```
 65226544.0000
```

Clearly, the console output is not what is being assigned to `x`.  Is there some finite precision result coming in to cause this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the variable and constant are single precision and only have about 7 decimal digits available.  Compare to:

```
program f1
  use, intrinsic :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
  implicit none
  real :: x=65226545.6525
  real (real64) :: y=65226545.6525_real64
  write(*,'(F14.4)') x
  write(*,'(F14.4)') y
end program f1
```

which uses a double-precision number via the ISO Fortran environment, specified as `real64`, i.e., 64 bits.   `real64` is also used on the constant, otherwise it will be evaluated as a single-precision constant, then stored in the double-precision variable `y`.    (If you need even more digits, you can use quadrupole precision, `real128`.)

Comment: real128 is quadruple precision (at least in the IEEE sense)

Comment: Very true.  Answer updated.